# What is this? Found in southern Illinois

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Found in southern Illinois in the driveway.  What is this?

Comment: It looks like a recently emerged periodic cicada that ran into some problems.

Comment: Was their grass / bushes around or just rocks?

Comment: Definitely a cicada.. it could be prematurely developed which has caused this milky characteristic to most of its body, and/or combined with environmental factors that could have effected it's outer coat. Is that possibly a bubble between the thorax and its left wing? Hmm..

Answer (score -1):

Nice find! It looks to me like a [Bush Cicada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neotibicen_dorsatus) or scientificly ***Neotibicen dorsatus***. It also looks like its injured, because we can see the white liquid around its wings and abdomen. Bush Cicadas tend to have a yellow or brown color but as shown here there is a wide variaty to the colourations that it might have:

**Size (Adult, Length)**: 35mm to 57mm (1.38in to 2.24in)

**Identifying Colors**: yellow, brown, ***white***, gold, black

North American Reach (Though Not Limited To*): Arizona; Arkansas; Colorado; ***Illinois***; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Nebraska; New Mexico; North Dakota; Oklahoma; South Dakota; Texas; Wyoming; Mexico.

Here are and some photos:

**Adults**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The cicada is black eyed and green and brown colored. Yours have red eyes, except for one. There are lots of different cicadas, though.

Comment: @anongoodnurse And it is extremelly difficult to find a WHITE identical... XD

Comment: Many cicadas emerge white. That's not the issue. Your ID is off.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks for the edit I will take care for it right away...

Comment: Do you have a source for what the fluids of a cicada look like? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am checking it on the net... Look it sure something like its blood or gastric liquids? Probably..

Answer (score -2):

It looks like a cicada of the Genus *Tibicen*, perhaps a "dog day" cicada (because of when they come out.)

[image]

Here are others of that genus; they're very similar.

[image]

Something is not right, though. I can't account for the white opaque liquid; even pictures of injured cicadas don't show it (at least that I can find.)

It looks like yours was dipped in Elmer's glue or something similar; the fluid is pooling under the wings and around the body. They usually hatch from a dry case, so I'm mystified.

Comment: About these white liquids you asked me, I checked and found that some cicadas "urinate" after the molt process, but the cicada above is a adult version...

Comment: Cicada urine is clear, and usually colorless or lightly colored.

Comment: Then I don't know... ran out of ideas.